# Javascript regex doesn't match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been stucked with this problem for hours. I have a regex pattern and a matching string. Regarding to [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/#javascript), it is sure a matching string, but in my script, regarding to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helmet91/wue82/), it doesn't match.

RegExp: `/\[img=?.*?http:\/\/lorempixel\.com\/640\/480.*?\/img\]/`

String to match: `[img=http://lorempixel.com/640/480]description[/img]`

Script: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helmet91/wue82/)

Can anyone find the problem here?

Comment: That's not how you build dynamic regex in JS, you need to use the `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: I have read somewhere (MDN or W3Schools), that strings convert to RegExp. Anyway, I am going to try your suggestion, thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, I tried it, aaaand, you are right! Thank you once again! @elclanrs

Comment: @helmet91 Just adding the RegExp constructor couldn't have fixed your problem.  If it worked then you must have fixed the improper escaping in your string as well.

Comment: @JamesMontagne My original question aimed the RegExp constructor problem. However, as you said, I have another problem as well, but I don't want to ask too mutch. :D First, I am struggling with this new problem for another few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't concatenate a regex using a regex literal, and you need a regex for the `.match` method.

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\[img=?.*?" + regexSafeUrl + ".*?\/img\\]");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wue82/1/

EDIT: James Montague is correct that `.match` will implicitly use a RegExp.  You don't need the `/` in the string that gets converted to RegExp though or these will be considered literal slashes.  Your real problem was doing this as well as not properly escaping in the string.

http://jsfiddle.net/wue82/3/

Comment: If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj).  [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: You missed one slash. The `/` before `/img` is still improperly escaped.  Though it doesn't cause a problem since `/` doesn't need to be escaped at all.